# Regular expression to capture the digits

Tags: regex, r

I have a following text (converted from html document), and I am trying to grab following elements:

a) alphabetical symbol(consisting of more than one and less than 10 alphabets ( only caps)

b) digits outside the parenthesis (can be decimal and with comma (if more than three digits) but not negative)

c) digits inside the first parenthesis (can be decimal and with comma (if more than three digits) but not negative)

d) digits inside the second parenthesis (can be decimal and with comma (if more than three digits) and negative)

Example: I want to have ADL, 280, 3524 (without comma) and 2 as four column  in a dataframe.

```
df1<-"ADL 280 ( 3,524 ) (  2 )          BDB 485 ( 1,618 ) (  -4 )          CPC 354 ( 5,899 ) (  3 )          EIC 405 ( 791 ) (  -11 )          ALDBL 333 ( 250 ) (  18 )          ALICL 1,262 ( 6,554 ) (  -9 )          ALICLP 410 ( 400 ) (  32 )          HPEX 142 ( 7,732 ) (  -1 )",
```

Here is my solution:

```
library(stringr)
# firm name with only alphabets
firms<-str_extract_all(df1,"[A-Z]{2,}") 
#split after the firm name 
split_firm<-strsplit(df1,"[A-Z]+[1]*") 
#split after the bracket 
split_bracket<-strsplit(split_firm[[1]],"\\(|\\)")
#rbind all values
rbind_values<-do.call(rbind,split_bracket)
#we need only only columns 1,2,4
values_matrix<-rbind_values[1:nrow(rbind_values),c(1,2,4)]
#combine values with firm names 
final_df<-data.frame(cbind(trade_com,data.frame(values_matrix)))
names(final_df)<-c("Firms","Inward","Outward","Difference") 
#convert cols into character and then 2:4 into numeric after removing commas
final_df[] <- lapply(final_df,as.character)
final_df[,2:4] <- lapply(final_df[,2:4], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))

Expected output: 
      Firms Inward Outward Difference
    1    ADL    280    3524          2
    2    BDB    485    1618         -4
    3    CPC    354    5899          3
    4    EIC    405     791        -11
    5  ALDBL    333     250         18
    6  ALICL   1262    6554         -9
    7 ALICLP    410     400         32
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to shorten the above code by using regular expression, e.g, capture the digits without parenthesis, digits inside the first and second parenthesis without string split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can just sub out the parentheses and commas and split by white space

```
df1 <- "ADL 280 ( 3,524 ) (  2 )          BDB 485 ( 1,618 ) (  -4 )          CPC 354 ( 5,899 ) (  3 )          EIC 405 ( 791 ) (  -11 )          ALDBL 333 ( 250 ) (  18 )          ALICL 1,262 ( 6,554 ) (  -9 )          ALICLP 410 ( 400 ) (  32 )          HPEX 142 ( 7,732 ) (  -1 )"

x <- gsub('\\(|\\)|,', '', df1)
## or more simply as thelatemail mentions in comments:
x <- gsub('[(),],', '', df1)
as.data.frame(matrix(strsplit(x, '\\s+')[[1]], ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#       V1   V2   V3  V4
# 1    ADL  280 3524   2
# 2    BDB  485 1618  -4
# 3    CPC  354 5899   3
# 4    EIC  405  791 -11
# 5  ALDBL  333  250  18
# 6  ALICL 1262 6554  -9
# 7 ALICLP  410  400  32
# 8   HPEX  142 7732  -1
```

then change the names and convert to numeric:

```
x <- setNames(x, c('Firms', 'Inward', 'Outward', 'Difference'))
x[, 2:4] <- lapply(x[, 2:4], as.numeric)
```

Comment: Perfect . I was looking for something like this. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. `gsub("[(),]","",x)` might be marginally simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **dplyr** approach.  Someone may have a more **dplyr**-y way to do this:

```
df1<-"ADL 280 ( 3,524 ) (  2 )          BDB 485 ( 1,618 ) (  -4 )          CPC 354 ( 5,899 ) (  3 )          EIC 405 ( 791 ) (  -11 )          ALDBL 333 ( 250 ) (  18 )          ALICL 1,262 ( 6,554 ) (  -9 )          ALICLP 410 ( 400 ) (  32 )          HPEX 142 ( 7,732 ) (  -1 )"

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyr)

df1 %>%
    strsplit("\\s{6,}") %>%
    unlist %>%
    data_frame(x=.) %>%
    extract(x, c("Firms", "Inward", "Outward", "Difference"), 
        "([A-Z]+)\\s+([0-9,]+)[ (]+([0-9,]+)[ )(]+([0-9-]+)") %>%
    mutate(
        Inward = extract_numeric(Inward),
        Outward = extract_numeric(Outward),
        Difference = extract_numeric(Difference)
    )

## Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
## 
##    Firms Inward Outward Difference
## 1    ADL    280    3524          2
## 2    BDB    485    1618         -4
## 3    CPC    354    5899          3
## 4    EIC    405     791        -11
## 5  ALDBL    333     250         18
## 6  ALICL   1262    6554         -9
## 7 ALICLP    410     400         32
## 8   HPEX    142    7732         -1
```

Here's the explanation of the regex both [visually](https://www.debuggex.com) and [verbally](http://regexper.com/) provided by `qdapRegex::explain` from the **qdapRegex** package that I maintain:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \\1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \\1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \\2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9,]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', ',' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \\2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ (]+                    any character of: ' ', '(' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \\3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9,]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', ',' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \\3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ )(]+                   any character of: ' ', ')', '(' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \\4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9-]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '-' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \\4
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does `]+`? do in `(]+([0-9,]+)[?`

Comment: I added explanation.  I think you're breaking the regex at the wrong points.

Comment: Oh. I got it. It was capturing the `parenthesis`.. Thanks.